# git - не добавляет файлы

Tags: git

Пытаюсь закинуть папку с файлами, пишет:

> неотслеживаемые файлы:
>          (используйте «git add <файл>…», чтобы добавить в то, что будет включено в коммит)
>
> frontend/doc/map-files/

Добавляет только  по одному командой `git add` с указанием полного пути. Но если у меня в папке несколько десятков файлов? Возможно, проблема, если ниже по дереву есть еще один репозиторий `.git`, но его вроде нет. Точнее, не знаю как его идентифицировать.

Comment: git add -A  или git add . не пробывал

Comment: ..Пробывал миллион раз)). ||  после данных команд добавляются все изменения в сопутствующих файлах, но те. что не создавались в репозитории, а были добавлены из другого источника - не добавляются...

Comment: @Help-myFather о каком "другом источнике" речь?

Comment: в смысле, просто перетаскиваю папку с рабочего стола в папку где установлен гит,  команндой git add .   пытаюсь добавить для последующего коммита ,не добавляет ... если ручками создать в консоли папку и добавлять туда по одному файлу командой "git add имя файла"  - то так добавляет, но добавить все содержимое  не выходит

Answer (score 1):

Используйте просто

```
git add frontend/doc/map-files
```

---

*Доказательство, что это заработало:*

Состояние перед командой
(см. примечание в конце моего ответа):

```
>git status
On branch master

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    frontend/doc/map-files/
```

Применение команды и состояние после этого:

```
>git add frontend/doc/map-files

>git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   frontend/doc/map-files/map-file1.txt
        new file:   frontend/doc/map-files/map-file2.txt
```

**Всё в порядке.**

---

*Примечание:*

Для этого доказательства я сначала создал такое дерево с папками и файлами в них:

```
C:.
|
\---frontend
    |   frontend-file1.txt
    |   frontend-file2.txt
    |
    \---doc
            doc-file1.txt
            doc-file2.txt
```

и сохранил всё через комит:

```
>git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        frontend/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

>git add frontend

>git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   frontend/doc/doc-file1.txt
        new file:   frontend/doc/doc-file2.txt
        new file:   frontend/frontend-file1.txt
        new file:   frontend/frontend-file2.txt

>git commit -m "Добавлено frontend/doc/"
[master b876620] Добавлено frontend/doc/
 4 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 frontend/doc/doc-file1.txt
 create mode 100644 frontend/doc/doc-file2.txt
 create mode 100644 frontend/frontend-file1.txt
 create mode 100644 frontend/frontend-file2.txt
```

Затем добавил в дерево папок/файлов папку `map-files`:

```
C:.
|
\---frontend
    |   frontend-file1.txt
    |   frontend-file2.txt
    |
    \---doc
        |   doc-file1.txt
        |   doc-file2.txt
        |
        \---map
                map-file1.txt
                map-file2.txt
```

и начал свое доказательство — см. начало моего ответа.